# why aren't these ellipses being placed correctly?

Tags: javascript, processing, trigonometry

Apparently I need to practice more trig.  I'm trying to position a number of circles equal to `categories.length` around a central axis.  Here's the code I'm using (p5.js):

```
var categoryX, categoryY;

   for (var j=0; j<categories.length; j++){                
        categoryX = width/2 + (250*cos(frameCount/3000) * cos(j*PI/categories.length));                
        categoryY = height/2 + (250*sin(frameCount/3000) * cos(j*PI/categories.length));         
        ellipse(categoryX, categoryY, 250, 250);
```

The circles should move with time (hence the frameCount) but also start along different radians of a circle.  This code doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not multiply the (co)sines. Instead, add their arguments together for use in one (co)sine. I also think you want to mutiply *j* with 2π, instead of π, so you cover the whole arc around the central point:

```
cos(frameCount/3000 + j*2*PI/categories.length)
```

Same for the sine.

So the code would become:

```
var categoryX, categoryY;

for (var j=0; j<categories.length; j++){                
    categoryX = width/2 + 250*cos(frameCount/3000 + j*2*PI/categories.length);
    categoryY = height/2 + 250*sin(frameCount/3000 + j*2*PI/categories.length);
    ellipse(categoryX, categoryY, 250, 250);
    // ...
}
```